# Using SUMX to calculate difference between versions

Tags: powerbi, dax

Not sure how to go about this but I feel like it is possible. Basically I have a set of data that is similar to what is shown below.

What I would like to be able to do is count how many contracts in each program had a change of greater than +-300.

For example, in this dataset, Project A Contract 1 changed by -400 and Project B Contract 2 changed by -400 so both Project A and Project B would have a count of 1.  Project A Contract 2 and Project B Contract 1 should not be counted because they did not change.

In my mind there is a way to do this with SUMX or such but I don't quite understand how to do this.

My thought is something on a take on this but really need some guidance.  Not sure how to get it down to the 'Contract' level.

Calculate(SUMX(DataTable,Amount),Version="Current") - Calculate(SUMX(DataTable,Amount),Version="Prior")

Much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this you have to create a summarized table and then form there you have to calculate the difference.

```
Measure = 
var tab = ADDCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZE('DataTable','DataTable'[Project],'DataTable'[Contract]),"sumval",sum('DataTable'[Amount]))
var cur = CALCULATE(SUMX(tab,[sumval]),'DataTable'[Version]="Current")
var priv = CALCULATE(SUMX(tab,[sumval]),'DataTable'[Version]="Prior")
return cur-priv
```

Comment: Wow that is interesting.  Thank you I will try to apply this tomorrow.  I need to do some more reading because I don't fully understand how the filter context would flow to the 'tab' table you created.  When you define the 'cur' VAR how does DAX know that the new 'tab' table created is related to the 'datatable' and  can have the 'Version' filter applied to it?  I think that is the part that confuses me.

Comment: Tried it out today and its not quite working.  Both the cur and priv have the same value.  Its as if the 'Version' filter in the Calculate function is not working.